# Android - Getting phone number of an address

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, phone-number

I am developing an app, where I am just finding an address based on a search, based on search I got the address latitude longitude and place Id, but I need one more thing -- Phone number of that address. When I read the Places API tuitorial it is return by `getPhoneNumber()`, but I couldn't find any proper tutorial for this, can anyone help me to find a tutorial for getting the phone number of an address.

Comment: google also provides temporary googlePlaceId for random lat, lng or address. you can get phone number of a place only if it is lised as a place in google maps (and if the place has an available phone number).

Comment: @ Rajeshwari... can u give more details..

Comment: I have used google place picker mostly. it shows places on map which places are listed. if you select a place that is listed, the activity will return details of the place. for example, if the selected place id a restaurant, you will receive opening hours, rating etc. but if you pin a random lat, lng the activity will return temporary google place id (which does not have any details as the place is not listed).

Answer (score 0):

if place has an available phone number

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Place place = PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(this, data);
                Log.i("Register", "Place: " + place.getName());

               // get phone number form place object
                String phonenumber = place.getPhoneNumber().toString();

                LatLng latLng = place.getLatLng();




            } else if (resultCode == PlaceAutocomplete.RESULT_ERROR) {
                Status status = PlaceAutocomplete.getStatus(this, data);
                // TODO: Handle the error.
                Log.i("Register", status.getStatusMessage());

            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // The user canceled the operation.
            }
        }
    }
```